# Using Rails 3.2, Should inclusion of conditional JavaScript in the views be avoided?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3.1, haml, ruby-on-rails-3.2

As everyone knows the Rails framework advices for strict separation of JavaScript and Html via what's called UJS, however sometimes, I find myself in the need to include impromptu snippets of JavaScripts in my Views. **First of all, I would like to know if this is correct at all? Or is it frowned upon?**

The most common case in which I find myself doing this, is when for example I have a condition block like this one:

```
= form_for @place do |f|
  %h5 Address:
  .input-prepend
    %span{ :class => "add-on" } 
      %i{ :class => "icon-road" }
    = f.text_field :address

  %h5 Name:
  .input-prepend
    %span{ :class => "add-on" } 
      %i{ :class => "icon-pencil" }
    = f.text_field :name

  = f.hidden_field :latitude
  = f.hidden_field :longitude

  #post-button
    %button{ :class => "btn btn-primary", :type => "submit" } Post it! 

- unless logged_in?
  :javascript
    $('#post-button > button, .input-prepend input').addClass('disabled');
    $('.input-prepend input').addClass('disabled');
    $('.input-prepend input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    new PopOver().setPopOver($('#post-button > button'), "You must be logged in to register your Business");
```

Take a look at the code nested within the unless condition, I wonder if *it's OK* to have it there, or **should I somehow generate that portion of code from a controller?** (and pass it(render it)to the view: In which case I have no idea how to do it...)

Please let me know your thoughts, I need to know how the most experienced of Rails developers would handle these type of situations, so, If you are one I'd love to read your answer.

Thanks in advance!

PS. Oh, and please let me see code options about how you would address this if possible, Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UJS is certainly the most popular approach in the Rails world currently, but different developers take it to different extremes.  Some developers I know shun it entirely because according to them you don't know if a particular element will be acted upon via JS when you are just looking at the html (which I personally think is fine, since HTML is just about structure, not functionality).

In terms of your particular issue, it is clear that you cannot simply just put the javascript into a regular javascript folder to be loaded with the page, because the javascript will not know if you are logged in.  You could put an indicator somewhere in the DOM indicating that you are logged in, but to me that would be too easy to spoof.  One fairly secure way to decide whether to run javascript based on data on the server is to make an AJAX call to the server, as follows:

1. Javascript loaded by the browser makes a get AJAX call to the server (using $.getScript() with jQuery)
2. The action in your Rails controller responds to the AJAX call with a .js.erb template
3. You can put as much server side logic as you would like into your .js.erb template (i.e. only run the javascript if the user is not logged in)

This way, you keep the javascript (functionality) out of your html (structure) while still being able to make server side decisions.  There is a similar scenario in the railscast for [dynamic page caching](http://railscasts.com/episodes/169-dynamic-page-caching-revised)

For example, if in your application.js you had:

```
$.getScript('/users/show')
```

Then this would call your `UsersController#show` action.  Rails would then look for the `app/views/users/show.js.erb` template.  In this file you could have the following:

```
<% unless logged_in? %>
  $('#post-button > button, .input-prepend input').addClass('disabled');
  $('.input-prepend input').addClass('disabled');
  $('.input-prepend input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  new PopOver().setPopOver($('#post-button > button'), "You must be logged in to register your Business");
<% end %>
```

The javascript would automatically run as soon as the response from the server is received by the browser.  In this case, it would only run the javascript if the user wasn't logged in.

Comment: Interesting, But let's see if I got this right... Are you saying that
inside the :javascript I make the $.get Ajax Call? and depending on the response I render a partial?
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I would personally create a javascript file for your page (in `assets/javascripts` if you are using the asset pipeline) where you would make the $getScript() call.  This file will run any time you access the page.  From there, you could either a) have the controller choose which .js.erb file to render based on certain conditions, or b) have a single .js.erb file similar to what you have above, where the javascript that is run varies depending on instance variables, controller variables, etc.  The latter is more straightforward, in my opinion.

This would keep the js out of your HAML entirely.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, But I suppose it's difficult to pass the condition you're talking about (in this case logged in or not) to javascript, right? I'd like to see a little code snippet if possible.
Thanks again Justin.

Comment: That's the beauty of crafting the response inside of a js.erb response from the server.  The js.erb template can include ruby code in just the same way that an html.erb template would.  Any javascript included in the js.erb template is automatically run in the browser when the server responds to $.getScript().  Note that since the browser made a request via JS (as opposed to HTML), rails will automatically look for a js.erb template to run.

Comment: That's a Fantastic Solution! I really had to say it because I previously didn't understand what you were trying to do. And of course I had no idea you could do an inclusion like this. It's really cool.
Thanks for this, very much.